# Probability:questions on characteristic functions

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, characteristic-functions

A well-known example to show that two random variables whose marginal distributions are normal, do not need necessarily be jointly normal is achieved by letting $X, Y $ have the following joint probability density function:
$$
f(x,y):= \frac{1}{\pi}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\cdot 1_{\{(x,y): xy>0\}}. 
$$

Unless I am doing something wrong, when I compute the characteristic function for $(X, Y), $ 
I end up with 
$$ \phi_{X, Y}(s, t) = e^{-(s^2+t^2)/2}. $$ 
This troubles me, because that is also the ch.f. for a bivariate normal distribution whose components are independent... Not sure if I am making some silly calculus mistake or if this result is correct.
I am computing the ch.f. as
$$ \phi_{X, Y}(s, t) = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{isx+ity}\frac{1}{\pi}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\, dx dy + \int_{-\infty}^0 \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{isx+ity}\frac{1}{\pi}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\, dx dy $$
and completing the square for the exponentials, i.e., for the first of the two integrals above
$$ \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{isx+ity}\frac{1}{\pi}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\, dx dy
$$

$$
=\frac{1}{\pi} e^{-t^2/2-s^2/2} \cdot \int_0^\infty e^{-(x^2- 2isx + (is)^2)/2} dx \int_0^\infty e^{-(y^2-2ity + (it)^2)/2} dy + ....$$

Now, both integrals computes at $\pi/2 $ as they are "half a normal" so that we get
$$ \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{isx+ity}\frac{1}{\pi}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\, dx dy
= \frac{1}{\pi} e^{-t^2/2-s^2/2} \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{1}{2} e^{-t^2/2-s^2/2}. $$
Doing the same for the integral $\int_{-\infty}^0 \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{isx+ity}\frac{1}{\pi}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\, dx dy $ gives my result which is strange because this is obviously not the pdf for a bivariate independent standard normal. Hence, I do believe something must have gone wrong at some points, but cannot see where.

Also, if $X $ is a given random variable and we consider the vector ${\bf Y}:= (X, X)^T, $ then its ch.f. is given by
$$ \phi_{{\bf Y}}(t_1, t_2) = \phi_X(t_1+t_2) $$
which is interesting as a result in itself. But, if I make the further assumption that $X \sim N(0, 1), $ then we end up with
$$ \phi_{{\bf Y}}(t_1, t_2) = e^{-(t_1+t_2)^2/2}. $$
Is this the ch.f. associated with a degenerate bivariate random variable? Technically, such a distribution does not have probability density function, but perhaps one could still get here using generalized inverses?

Thank you for any help,

Maurice

Comment: First question: "Unless I am doing something wrong, when I compute the characteristic function for (X,Y), I end up with..." If you end up with this then yes you are doing something wrong. But we cannot say what since you do not show what you did. Second question: "Is this the ch.f. associated with a degenerate bivariate random variable?" Yes it is. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Despite the edit, in the first part we still have no idea how you "end up with" 
$\phi_{X, Y}(s, t) = e^{-(s^2+t^2)/2}$.